# Node .JS Crawler to JSON output is empty

Tags: json, node.js, dom, web-crawler

So I am trying my hand at Node.js. I want to build a simple crawler which scans a page and then returns all links back in a json file. However, when I run the script it returns 0 links.

Here is my code in its entirety:

```
    var request = require('request');
    var cheerio = require('cheerio');
    var fs = require("fs");

    var url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions';

    //Create the blank array to fill:
    var obj = {
       table: []
    };

    var i = 0;

    request(url, function(err, resp, body){
      $ = cheerio.load(body);
      links = $('a'); //jquery get all hyperlinks

      $(links).each(function(i, link){
        var actualLink = $(link).attr('href');
          obj.table.push({id: i, url:actualLink}); //add some data
          i++;
      });

    }); 

    var json = JSON.stringify(obj);

    console.log(json);
```

The output in the terminal is so:

> $ !!
>
> node nodetest.js
>
> {"table":[]}

Can anyone see why this is blank? Bonus points for writing the final json to a file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `obj` **inside** the success callback of the request, that's where it gets populated:

```
request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    links = $('a'); //jquery get all hyperlinks

    $(links).each(function(i, link) {
        var actualLink = $(link).attr('href');
        obj.table.push({id: i, url:actualLink}); //add some data
    });

    // Only here you can be sure that the "obj" variable is properly
    // populated because that's where the HTTP request completes
    var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
    console.log(json);
});
```

In your code you have placed the `console.log` outside the request success which is asynchronous and thus the `obj` variable is not yet populated.

Also notice that you don't need the `i` variable. It will be passed to the `each` callback automatically, you don't need to be explicitly declaring or incrementing it.

As far as writing the result to a file is concerned, you could use the `fs.writeFile` function:

```
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", json, function(err) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log("File successfully saved");
    }
});
```

Comment: This says file successful buy then didn't do anything. I changed "/tmp/test" to "test.json" and it worked.